# Unable to update

Tags: updates, release-hera

Getting this error:

> E: The repository 'cdrom://elementary OS 5.1 *hera* - stable amd64
>   (20191202) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have enable your CD-rom as part of your sourcelist. You need to disable it.

Open the terminal and type (or copy/paste):

```
sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Set a **#** infront where it says **deb cd-rom**

So it looks like this:
**# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.1 *hera* - stable amd64 (20191202)]/ bionic contrib main non-free**

Save: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
exit: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Now try again running the update:

```
sudo apt update
```